# How to install libcurl under MacOS10.12 and use for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, curl, libcurl

[Building libCURL for iOS 4.2](http://www.creativealgorithms.com/blog/content/building-libcurl-ios-42)

Hello Guys:
      This is my first stack overflow question. I have read the blog posted before but I still cannot finish building. I am not familiar with the terminal programming. First let me show you some basic info about xcode on my mac.

```
`Wuqians-MBP:~ wuqianzhong$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
Wuqians-MBP:~ wuqianzhong$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`
```

Then I typed the following 4 lines learned from the blog [Building libCURL for iOS 4.2.](http://www.creativealgorithms.com/blog/content/building-libcurl-ios-42)

```
export CC=“/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang”

export CFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -pipe -Os -gdwarf-2 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Deveoper/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk"

export LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk"

 ./configure --host=x86_64-apple-darwin --with-zlib --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-ipv6 --disable-manual --disable-verbose
```

However, the result shows that I am not building correctly. Even the C complier is not working.

```
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable debug build options... no
checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... (assumed) yes
checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings... no
checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors... no
checking whether to enable curl debug memory tracking... no
checking whether to enable hiding of library internal symbols... yes
checking whether to enable c-ares for DNS lookups... no
checking whether to disable dependency on -lrt... (assumed no)
checking for path separator... :
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for x86_64-apple-darwin-ar... no
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for x86_64-apple-darwin-gcc... “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang”
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/wuqianzhong/Desktop/curl-7.52.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: How about `./configure`, `make` and `make install` ?

Comment: Without seeing config.log, it's anybody's guess.  You might not have agreed to the terms and conditions in Xcode, or it might be missing a critical library, or the configure script could be adding bogus flags, or....  The config.log file should tell what went wrong in compilation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[How to install libcurl in Mac](https://xuhp.gitbooks.io/fragmentary-knowledge/content/mac/%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E5%9C%A8Mac%E4%B8%AD%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85libcurl.html)

Hey, I think I have found the answer and it works!

1. Download [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) install package and extract it
2. Use terminal to enter curl install package folder root directory
3. Set install path:  `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/curl`
4. Compile: `make`
5. Install: `sudo make install`

Then you will find curl in path /usr/local/curl with four documents
bin, include, lib, share.

Comment: Hey guys, I find another way much easier to use libcurl on Mac xcode. Mac OS has already created it and you can directly find it in /usr/lib/libcurl.dylib and add it to your xcode project.

Comment: where you set it?

Comment: This answer is way to simple. You will need a lot more configure options to install curl. It has become it's own dll dependency hell if you want to compile it with most features on.