# Kotlin Multiplatform Ktor linux compile error: unable to find library -lcurl

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-native, ktor-client

I'm trying to build native binaries for Linux with a Kotlin Multi-Platform project that has Ktor dependency. However when I run the task `nativeBinaries` I'm getting the following error:

```
e: /Users/<user>/.konan/dependencies/clang-llvm-apple-8.0.0-darwin-macos/bin/ld.lld invocation reported errors

The /Users/<user>/.konan/dependencies/clang-llvm-apple-8.0.0-darwin-macos/bin/ld.lld command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lcurl
```

The project is a simple one with the following dependencies

```
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.5.4")
            }
        }
        val nativeMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-curl:1.5.4")
            }
        }
```

It builds successfully if I remove ktor client curl dependency from `nativeMain`.
I have `curl` installed on my local environment (I'm using mac), Am I missing something? Do I need to do any other configurations to get rid of this error?

Comment: Is the `libcurl-dev` package installed?

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish it really worked when I compile on Linux. I'm trying to install `libcurl-dev` on Mac and couldn't find a way as `brew` doesn't recognize the package. I'll take a look

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709808/13963150 you can find an instruction about curl installation from sources on macOS.